# How to have a scaleable docker cluster with a reverse proxy and load balancer serving several sites from one VM

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, containers, load-balancing

I and trying to setup a scaleable platform that will not only scale itself but any other applications running on this platform on one host (VM).

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIWtk.png)

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy 
this has a reverse proxy that points the site requested (eg. hello.example.com) to the docker with that env (environment variable) value.

The only thing that is missing  in this setup is to be able to spin up load balancer containers for each different host (web application) so you can scale the web app also.

Answer (score 0):

Docker clusters normally span more than one machine running the docker engine.

I suspect what you're looking for is a solution that supports the deployment of multiple applications on a single server? For the neatest PAAS you'll ever reverse engineer, check out Dokku:

http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/

Comment: I am looking for something that will also work on multiple machines in the same way. But i haven't had much luck finding one.

Comment: If you're interested in a multi-server Dokku implementation and are willing to sponsor a bit of work on it, let me know and I'd be happy to look into it for you (I'm one of the maintainers).

Comment: i don't see why nobody else has ran into the same problem as I did. lol

Comment: @isethi I think your question is confusing. If you're looking for a docker orchestration solution that will load balance your docker containers, take a look at Kubernetes. Thing is that normally runs across multiple VMs. If you liked Dokku and crave something running across multiple machine I suggest looking at Deis (which happens to deploy on top of Kubernetes). Hope that helps